# VBA - Word Table : default value and combo box

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have Word Tables, and I don't find how to affect default values for certain columns...
When inserting a new line, I would like a certain column to have a certain drop-down list without user having to do it himself.

To illustrate my thoughts, here is a small image of what I'm looking for

[image: model]

I really don't find how to manipulate my table for it to ends up like this, so I would like to request your help.
When looking on the web for this, I only find information about table default style and no default Value.

So I would like to ask. Is this possible? 
If yes, how to do it?

I am looking for either a VBA code to set my column default value *(which would be great)*, or even a way to do it in Word GUI at first. Or, obviously, an answer that would tell me that it is impossible to do in Word.

PS: the extremely easy equivalent in Excel of what i'm looking for:

[image: Easy Excel]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the GUI:

1. Click the cell where you would like your dropdown.
2. In menu, switch to "Developer Tools"
3. Insert a Dropdown control ("Controls" are, the one in the middle)
4. In the ribbon, click "Design mode" (I have German Word so the actual name might differ), "Properties"
5. Now you can enter your options

Alternatively via VBA, I got this with the macro recorder; should give you a start:

```
[Cell].Range.ContentControls.Add (wdContentControlComboBox)
ActiveDocument.ToggleFormsDesign
Selection.ParentContentControl.DropdownListEntries.Clear
Selection.ParentContentControl.DropdownListEntries.Add Text:="Yes", Value _
    :="Yes"
Selection.ParentContentControl.DropdownListEntries.Add Text:="No", Value:= _
    "No"
```

Comment: My problem isn't creating the drop-down list, it is putting it automatically in all the rows, even the new ones that are yet to be created.

Comment: @Zawarudio I have the same problem, did you make progress?

Comment: @skatun Sadly, I didn't find a solution to my problem in VBA, but you can probably easily do it with C#, if you really need it